# How to read filenames in a folder and access them in an alphabetical and increasing number order?

Tags: python, list, filenames, glob

I would like to ask how to efficiently handle accessing of filenames in a folder in the right order (alphabetical and increasing in number).

For example, I have the following files in a folder: apple1.dat, apple2.dat, apple10.dat, banana1.dat, banana2.dat, banana10.dat. I would like to read the contents of the files such that apple1.dat will be read first and banana10.dat will be read last.

Thanks.

This is what I did so far.

```
from glob import glob
files=glob('*.dat')
for list in files
# I read the files here in order
```

But as pointed out, apple10.dat comes before apple2.dat

Comment: It'd help if you let us know what you already tried, so we can avoid discussion that in the answers. What problems did you encounter when you did what you did, etc.

Comment: Remember that the natural order files normally are sorted in is using the letters ASCII values, which will place e.g. `apple10.dat` after `apple1.dat` but _before_ `apple2.dat`.

Comment: You copied my answer but you have forgotten to sort the files list using sorted() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from glob import glob
import os

files_list = glob(os.path.join(my_folder, '*.dat'))
for a_file in sorted(files_list):
  # do whatever with the file
  # 'open' or 'with' statements depending on your python version
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

```
import os

def get_sorted_files(Directory)
    filenamelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Directory):
        for name in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(root, name)
            filenamelist.append(fullname)
    return sorted(filenamelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the numbers to an int first.  Doing it the long way would require breaking the names into the strings and numbers, casting the numbers to an int and sorting.  Perhaps someone else has a shorter or more efficient way.

```
    def split_in_two(str_in):
        ## go from right to left until a letter is found   
        ## assume first letter of name is not a digit
        for ctr in range(len(str_in)-1, 0, -1):
            if not str_in[ctr].isdigit():
                return str_in[:ctr+1], str_in[ctr+1:]  ## ctr+1 = first digit
        ## default for no letters found
        return str_in, "0"

    files=['apple1.dat', 'apple2.dat', 'apple10.dat', 'apple11.dat', 
           'banana1.dat', 'banana10.dat', 'banana2.dat']
    print sorted(files)   ## sorted as you say

    sort_numbers = []
    for f in files:
        ## split off '.dat.
        no_ending = f[:-4]
        str_1, str_2 = split_in_two(no_ending)
        sort_numbers.append([str_1, int(str_2), ".dat"])
    sort_numbers.sort()
    print sort_numbers
```