# How do I sort a list of images alphanumerically in python?

Tags: python

I have a folder with a bunch of images, I convert them to 16:9 and then export them into another folder, everything works fine except that when importing the images they dont get stored sorted meaning when exporting they are in a completely different order, what can i do??

```
for filepath in glob.iglob(folderToEdit + '\*.jpg'):
imageList.append(filepath)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read filenames in a folder and access them in an alphabetical and increasing number order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953824/how-to-read-filenames-in-a-folder-and-access-them-in-an-alphabetical-and-increas)

Comment: Folders don't have an order. Read all filenames from the folder and sort them yourself according to the criteria that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them just after retrieving the filenames:

```py
for filepath in sorted(glob.iglob(folderToEdit + '\*.jpg')):
    imageList.append(filepath)
```

Additionally, if you want to ignore cases, you can do it by specifying the key parameter as the lowercase version of those filenames:

```py
for filepath in sorted(glob.iglob(folderToEdit + '\*.jpg'), key=lambda x: x.lower()):
    imageList.append(filepath)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qmgOsIF still does not work :/